# How to rewrite this equation?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel, series, conductance

How can the following equation which represents two series resistors (a & c) in parallel with a third resistor (b) be written in terms of conductance?

[image]

Comment: Trivial: \$R=\frac{G_a+G_c}{G_a G_b+G_a G_c + G_b G_c}\$

Answer (score 2):

[Conductance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) is reciprocal of resistance.

$$G=\frac{1}{R}$$